# Read a list of files into stream

Tags: java, file, java-8, stream, directory

I want to validate some links which are generated by my application. These generated files contain loads of lines I want to match with a regex to check if they are correct.

Where I'm stuck: I have a List of my files already declared and I want to open them into a stream so I can do some fancy Java coding with streams.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
   return !(Files.lines(Path.of(String.valueOf(FileList)))
      .anyMatch(v -> !v.matches(pattern));
```

The files are in the project's working directory so they only need a filename to access them. I want to read the files line by line to check for the incorrect lines. Is this the way to read a list of files with streams? If you know of any other way to make this work with streams please share. Many thanks!

Comment: Can you rephrase your question. Do you want a list of files? A stream of files? The files? Or the contents of the files? What is it exactly that you want?

Comment: A `Path` represents exactly one file. You can’t just take the string representation of a list and cram it into an API designed to process one element. You may stream over the list and use `flatMap` from the stream of files to the stream of lines. Besides that, `! stream .anyMatch(v -> ! condition)` is the same as `stream .allMatch(v -> condition)`…

Comment: `Files.lines()` read all lines from one file as a stream, but not a list of files

Answer (score 0):

> I have a List of my files already declared

Assuming that is your `FileList` variable<sup>1</sup>, and that it is a `List<String>` (unspecified in question), then you would do something like this:

```
Predicate<String> matches = Pattern.compile(pattern).asMatchPredicate();
return FileList.stream().allMatch(f -> {
    try {
        return Files.lines(Paths.get(f)).allMatch(matches);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
```

<sup>1) Java naming convention specifies that variable names should start with lowercase letter.</sup>

Comment: Almost the answer I was looking for, however this still expects a return statement at the end of the block. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Nodedesign Don't know what you mean by that. Your code has a `return` statement, so this code has a return statement. If you're referring to the other return statement, it is necessary because you have to catch the `IOException`. No way around that.